# My svn status shows “G”. How do I fix that?

Tags: linux

```
G    testmineExport.class.php

Updated to revision 549.
```

/*When trying to update the script called testmineExport.class.php, at that time 'G' status has appeared */

Comment: A  +  C application/testbed/filtered.log

Answer (score 12):

It means that you locally modified `testmineExport.class.php` and svn just merged upstream changes into that file. If there was a merge conflict status would be `C`.

Comment: Is it considered as conflict? Any problem will occur because of that status?

Comment: Commit your changes with `svn commit`. And no, as I said a conflict would be `C`. This is normal and won't cause any problems.